# How should I structure sentences in a series

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, lists

Lets say I have the following sentences...

> Cake is really bad for you. It contains a large amount of sugar. It contains common allergens. It looks silly.

Additionally, lets say I wanted to connect all three of these thoughts together in a similar manner...

> Cake is really bad for you. It contains a large amount of sugar. It contains common allergens. And, it looks silly.

Now, I know that using an "And" at the beginning of the sentence is poor grammar. I also realize this is more of a paragraph structure, so I could do some word-smithing to make it work that way.

However, this feels a lot like a series of items, and I would really love to treat it as such...

> Cake is really bad for you:  it contains a large amount of sugar; it contains common allergens; and it looks silly.

Is there a structure in the English language that provides for this? Is the above the proper usage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dash and commas to separate each of the explanatory thoughts.  Removing the redundant pronouns and verbs makes it even cleaner.

> Cake is really bad for you - it contains a large amount of sugar,
>   common allergens, and looks silly.

Comment: Tvanfosson, that's a good suggestion, but it lacks parallelism. Also, I would use a colon instead of a dash since the second clause explains the first clause.  My suggestion would be this:  

    _Cake is really bad for you: it not only looks silly, but also contains a large amount of sugar and common allergens._